# Compile error at structure definition which has the member of type, pointer to structure array in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, structure

First, here is the code making error below

```
typedef struct alpha_node_t_ {
    struct alpha_node_t_ (*nodePtr)[(26)][(8)];
} alpha_node_t;
```

When compiling this code in VS 2017, it works well and no warning happens.

however when it runs at C11: gcc 4.9.2, I face below error at this code.

```
submission.c:15:26: error: array type has incomplete element type
  struct alpha_node_t_ (* nodePtr)[(26)][(8)];
                          ^
```

What is problem? I think because the type of member is pointer anyway, the member size would be fixed or compiler would know the member size.

How dose gcc make the error at the point, VS2017 does not?
What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Looks like a difference between C and C++ -- is your VS 2017 properly configured to compile C? Try `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error misconfigured compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: It seems that __cplusplus is not defined in VS 2017 when I compile this source. There is no change.

Comment: What's the output of `printf("sizeof 42 - sizeof '*' is %d\n", (int)(sizeof 42) - (int)(sizeof '*'));`? If it's not `0` you are not using a C compiler.

Comment: The result is zero..

Comment: Does standard C11 not allow the pointer of struct array to be a member in structure?

Comment: The problem is nt the pointer. It's the struct itself: You are trying to define it recursevily (using `struct alpha_node_t_` as an array of `struct alpha_node_t_`s) but the *outside* definition is only complete at the `:`. Note that `struct alpha_node_t_ { struct alpha_node_t_ *nodePtr[26][8]; };` specifies an array of pointers, not a recursive array. Why VS2017 properly configured accepts the code is beyond me.

Comment: when I use g++, compile succeeded.. It seems C11 does not support such a situation..
And i found that VS 2017 use c++14 in default. Thank you for your suggestion about the difference btw compiler

Comment: I have curious point that ```struct alpha_node_t (*nodePtr)[26][8]``` is allowed to be a member of structure and ```struct alpha_node_t identifier``` is not in VS2017.
are they same recursive case?

Comment: You can have pointers to the struct itself, but not the struct, either directly or in array.

Comment: I think what you have as a member is not a pointer to another struct of the same type but a pointer to a 2D array of structs.